# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment. ("f" is just defined variable)

Tags: curve-fitting

I have a calculating and fitting code(below is some part of it).

```
    def NFW(self, r, r_s, c):

        x = r/r_s

        delta_c = (200/3) * (c**3 / (log(1+c) - (c/(1+c))))
        surface_mass_density = (c_velocity**2 / (4*pi*G)) * (self.D_s / (self.D_l * self.D_ls))
        rho_c = self.Cosmological_Model.critical_density(self.z_l).to(u.M_sun/(u.Mpc)**3).value
        Kk = ( 2*r_s*delta_c*rho_c ) / surface_mass_density
        
        # Kappa of NFW
        K_NFW = np.array([])
        for i in range(len(r)):
            if 0 <= x[i] <1:
                f = ( 1 / (x[i]**2-1) ) * ( 1 - ( 2*atanh( np.sqrt( ( (1-x[i]) / (1+x[i]) ) ) ) / np.sqrt(1-x[i]**2) ) )
            elif x[i] == 1:
                f = 1/3
            elif 1 < x[i]:
                f = ( 1 / (x[i]**2-1) ) * ( 1 - ( 2*atan( np.sqrt( (x[i]-1) / (1+x[i]) ) ) / np.sqrt(x[i]**2-1) ) )
            else:
                print("x[i] can not have negative number!")
            K_NFW = np.append(K_NFW, Kk * f)
```

And I tried to fit it with "scipy.curve_fit".

But the strange things is that sometimes it works, some times it dose not work depending on "r" which is one of the input parameter "NFW" function

below is fitting code.

```
ind_sub_R01 = np.where(self.obs_sub_R_LensPlane>0.10)#(<--this)
# If I put this '0.10' it doesn't work but if I put this '0.20' it works. 
# This number means cut of the radius which is fitting start point.

def NFW_fitting(self, main_NFW_p0, main_NFW_bounds, sub_NFW_p0, sub_NFW_bounds):
        main_popt, main_pcov = curve_fit(self.NFWfunc, self.obs_main_R_LensPlane, self.obs_main_r_T_avg, p0=main_NFW_p0, bounds=main_NFW_bounds)
        sub_popt, sub_pcov = curve_fit(self.NFWfunc, self.obs_sub_R_LensPlane, self.obs_sub_r_T_avg, p0=sub_NFW_p0, bounds=sub_NFW_bounds)
        return main_popt[0], main_popt[1], main_pcov, sub_popt[0], sub_popt[1], sub_pcov
```

IF I put 'this' '0.1', I face the error like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/42/grbryvqx3vndy45_5d7lxyqr0000gn/T/ipykernel_34140/3894437891.py in <module>
    198 drz_sci_606 = fits.open('bullet_f606w_drz_sci.fits')
    199 FITandPLOT = profile_FITandPLOT(reduced_shear_main=reduced_shear_main, reduced_shear_sub=reduced_shear_sub, SISfunc=profile.SIS, NFWfunc=profile.NFW, data_for_WCS=drz_sci_606, D_l=profile.D_l)
--> 200 FITandPLOT.plotting(main_SIS_p0=v_disp_main, main_SIS_bounds=[v_disp_main-5,v_disp_main+5], sub_SIS_p0=v_disp_sub, sub_SIS_bounds=[v_disp_main-5,v_disp_main+5],
    201                     main_NFW_p0=(r_s_main,c_vir_main), main_NFW_bounds=([r_s_main-5,c_vir_main-5], [r_s_main+5,c_vir_main+5]), sub_NFW_p0=(r_s_sub,c_vir_sub), sub_NFW_bounds=([r_s_sub-5,c_vir_sub-5], [r_s_sub+5,c_vir_sub+5]))
    202 

/var/folders/42/grbryvqx3vndy45_5d7lxyqr0000gn/T/ipykernel_34140/3894437891.py in plotting(self, main_SIS_p0, main_SIS_bounds, sub_SIS_p0, sub_SIS_bounds, main_NFW_p0, main_NFW_bounds, sub_NFW_p0, sub_NFW_bounds)
     59     def plotting(self, main_SIS_p0, main_SIS_bounds, sub_SIS_p0, sub_SIS_bounds, main_NFW_p0, main_NFW_bounds, sub_NFW_p0, sub_NFW_bounds):
     60         main_SIS_v_disp, main_SIS_err_v_disp, sub_SIS_v_disp, sub_SIS_err_v_disp = self.SIS_fitting(main_SIS_p0, main_SIS_bounds, sub_SIS_p0, sub_SIS_bounds)
---> 61         main_NFW_r_s, main_NFW_c, main_NFW_err_matrix, sub_NFW_r_s, sub_NFW_c, sub_NFW_err_matrix = self.NFW_fitting(main_NFW_p0, main_NFW_bounds, sub_NFW_p0, sub_NFW_bounds)
     62 
     63         #----main

/var/folders/42/grbryvqx3vndy45_5d7lxyqr0000gn/T/ipykernel_34140/3894437891.py in NFW_fitting(self, main_NFW_p0, main_NFW_bounds, sub_NFW_p0, sub_NFW_bounds)
     54     def NFW_fitting(self, main_NFW_p0, main_NFW_bounds, sub_NFW_p0, sub_NFW_bounds):
     55         main_popt, main_pcov = curve_fit(self.NFWfunc, self.obs_main_R_LensPlane, self.obs_main_r_T_avg, p0=main_NFW_p0, bounds=main_NFW_bounds)
---> 56         sub_popt, sub_pcov = curve_fit(self.NFWfunc, self.obs_sub_R_LensPlane, self.obs_sub_r_T_avg, p0=sub_NFW_p0, bounds=sub_NFW_bounds)
     57         return main_popt[0], main_popt[1], main_pcov, sub_popt[0], sub_popt[1], sub_pcov
     58 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/first_envs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    798             kwargs['max_nfev'] = kwargs.pop('maxfev', None)
    799 
--> 800         res = least_squares(func, p0, jac=jac, bounds=bounds, method=method,
    801                             **kwargs)
    802 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/first_envs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py in least_squares(fun, x0, jac, bounds, method, ftol, xtol, gtol, x_scale, loss, f_scale, diff_step, tr_solver, tr_options, jac_sparsity, max_nfev, verbose, args, kwargs)
    926 
    927     elif method == 'trf':
--> 928         result = trf(fun_wrapped, jac_wrapped, x0, f0, J0, lb, ub, ftol, xtol,
    929                      gtol, max_nfev, x_scale, loss_function, tr_solver,
    930                      tr_options.copy(), verbose)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/first_envs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/trf.py in trf(fun, jac, x0, f0, J0, lb, ub, ftol, xtol, gtol, max_nfev, x_scale, loss_function, tr_solver, tr_options, verbose)
    121             loss_function, tr_solver, tr_options, verbose)
    122     else:
--> 123         return trf_bounds(
    124             fun, jac, x0, f0, J0, lb, ub, ftol, xtol, gtol, max_nfev, x_scale,
    125             loss_function, tr_solver, tr_options, verbose)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/first_envs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/trf.py in trf_bounds(fun, jac, x0, f0, J0, lb, ub, ftol, xtol, gtol, max_nfev, x_scale, loss_function, tr_solver, tr_options, verbose)
    336 
    337             x_new = make_strictly_feasible(x + step, lb, ub, rstep=0)
--> 338             f_new = fun(x_new)
    339             nfev += 1
    340 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/first_envs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py in fun_wrapped(x)
    813 
    814     def fun_wrapped(x):
--> 815         return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))
    816 
    817     if method == 'trf':

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/first_envs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    483     if transform is None:
    484         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 485             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    486     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    487         def func_wrapped(params):

/var/folders/42/grbryvqx3vndy45_5d7lxyqr0000gn/T/ipykernel_34140/2654829019.py in NFW(self, r, r_s, c)
    142             else:
    143                 print("x[i] can not have negative number!")
--> 144             K_NFW = np.append(K_NFW, Kk * f)
    145 
    146         # Gamma of NFW

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

If I put 'this' '0.20' or '0.09', '0.25', I can obtain the fitting graph parameter well.

And these number mean the fitting start point like below
[image]

If I put the number '0.25', I fit the graph only right of '0.25' region.

I want to know why the error occurs.

Comment: ```f``` isn't defined in the ```else``` block, so after it runs ```print("x[i] can not have negative number!")```, it'll give you that error.

Comment: Oh, I see. thank you for your comment. But if the code enters the "else block", why they don't print "x[i] can not have negative number!"?

Comment: Try printing out what the value of x[i] is before ```K_NFW = np.append(K_NFW, Kk * f)```